# Clear cookies from Controller in Blazor

Tags: authentication, .net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor

I have a Blazor app authenticated through IdentityServer, when the Refresh token has expired the user should be automatically logged out from the application. When the user is performing actions, they invoke a *RequestHelper* class that calls a Gateway in charge of returning the data.

This *RequestHelper* class knows when the Refresh token has expired and can make a request to the LogoutController. However the cookies are not cleared from IdentityServer when the *LogoutController* is called this way. If the user navigates to /logout then it works fine (cookies are cleared and user is redirected), however when calling the *LogoutController* as an HTTP request from *RequestHelper* then the cookies are not cleared and the user is not redirected, it's like if it wasn't called at all, however the controller is indeed being reached.

```
public class RequestHelper : IRequestHelper
{
    private readonly TokenProvider _tokenProvider;
    private readonly AppContext _appContext;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public RequestHelper(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory,
                         TokenProvider tokenProvider,
                         IConfiguration configuration,
                         AppContext appContext)
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        _httpClientFactory = clientFactory;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _appContext = appContext;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetRequest(string url)
    {
        string jsonStringData = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ServerAPI"))
            {
                var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

                var token = _tokenProvider.AccessToken;
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token) && client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization == null)
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.Trim());
                }

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + url);
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    TokenResponse tokenResponse = await RefreshAccessToken();

                    token = _tokenProvider.AccessToken;
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                    {
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.Trim());
                        response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + url);
                    }
                }

                jsonStringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            jsonStringData = ex.Message;
        }

        return jsonStringData;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Requests a new token using the refresh token
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<TokenResponse> RefreshAccessToken()
    {
        string authority = _configuration.GetValue("Authority", "https://localhost:44327");
        string currentUrl = _configuration.GetValue("CurrentUrl", "https://localhost:44367");
        using (HttpClient serverClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
        {
            var discoveryDocument = await serverClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(authority);
            var refreshToken = _tokenProvider.RefreshToken;
            using (HttpClient refreshTokenClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
            {
                TokenResponse tokenResponse = await refreshTokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(
                    new RefreshTokenRequest
                    {
                        Address = discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint,
                        RefreshToken = refreshToken,
                        ClientId = "morpheusmanage",
                        ClientSecret = "secret"
                    });

                _tokenProvider.AccessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
                _tokenProvider.RefreshToken = tokenResponse.RefreshToken;

                // Logout
                if (tokenResponse.RefreshToken == null)
                {
                    using (HttpClient logoutClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
                    {
                        await logoutClient.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}/logout", currentUrl));
                    }
                }

                return tokenResponse;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class LogoutController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("logout")]
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");

        // Build redirect URI
        var request = HttpContext.Request;
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
        uriBuilder.Scheme = request.Scheme;
        uriBuilder.Host = request.Host.Host;
        uriBuilder.Path = request.Path.ToString();
        uriBuilder.Port = request.Host.Port.GetValueOrDefault();
        uriBuilder.Query = request.QueryString.ToString();

        var prop = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            RedirectUri = uriBuilder.Uri.ToString()
        };
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc", prop);
    }
}
```

To reiterate the controller exhibits the expected behaviour when typing the */logout* Url on the browser, however when being called from the *RequestHelper* class using HttpClient it doesn't have the right behaviour.

Comment: Cookies are associated with the http context / request (they live in the headers). If you make a new one, rather than use the current one, it's not going to work out. Not sure why you have three different clients in here.

Comment: If I have the same client for all requests the headers for the different users can be mixed up, since client will be a static variable

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that reasoning. Generally with Blazor you'd DI the client factory and just have it be injected as a transient. - ah, i'm used to wasm blazor. checking for server side

Comment: Okay, yeah, still not sure I follow your concern - the documentation says each call to CreateClient makes a new instance. You're constructing 3 different ones here all in the same method. They get disposed. Can you elaborate on the concern? I suspect it's not logging out because you made a new client for that logout so the context and headers are not in the main context.

Comment: Alright thanks you have given me an idea, I'll update this thread

Comment: Even if I add the DefaultRequestHeaders in logoutClient still it doesn't exhibit the required behaviour. The AccessToken comes from _tokenProvider which is scoped